# Using AnimationDrawable: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap

Tags: android, animation, bitmap, animationdrawable

I'm using Animation drawable to display a gif. I split the gif into frames, I created an animation file and I load it using:

```
animationImageView.setImageResource(splashAnimationResource);       
animation = (AnimationDrawable) animationImageView.getDrawable();
```

All this happens inside onResume(). After the animation has been displayed, inside onPause() I try to free memory:

```
for (int frameCounter = 0; frameCounter < animation.getNumberOfFrames(); ++frameCounter) {
        Drawable frame = animation.getFrame(frameCounter);
        if (frame instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            BitmapDrawable castedFrame = (BitmapDrawable) frame;
            Bitmap bitmap = castedFrame.getBitmap();
            if (bitmap != null && !bitmap.isRecycled())
                bitmap.recycle();
        }
        frame.setCallback(null);
    }
splashAnimation.setCallback(null);
```

This all works very nice, animation is displayed correctly and memory is freed. If I try to go to the animation activity again, first time it works, but then it throws an exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@2ee1a817
        at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfCannotDraw(Canvas.java:1225)
        at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawBitmap(GLES20Canvas.java:600)
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:544)
        at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer.draw(DrawableContainer.java:76)
        at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1187)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16269)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15192)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15215)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15990)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3708)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3502)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15187)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15215)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15990)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3708)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3502)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15187)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15215)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15990)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3708)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3502)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15187)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15215)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15990)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3708)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3502)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16272)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:3047)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15192)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15215)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:307)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:313)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:352)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2811)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2634)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2222)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1230)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6726)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6141)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

I am really confused. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry for asking this late.. but did u get the solution for this?

Comment: Not really. After many days of trying I switched to displaying a video :(

Comment: Would you post your solution? I'm sure it will be valuable

Comment: yup sure..just give me a min

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution after banging my head for a couple of days. First you need to create smaller images size, for instance I was first using 400x400 size frames.. then i reduced to 100x100. Then i removed all the codes for bitmap recycling as there isn't any solution for this problem. Then u just play with `animation.start()` and `.stop()` and it would be really good.